# Invalid argument error when attempting to save pandas dataframe to a workspace directory in databricks

Tags: python, pandas, databricks

I am attempting to save a pandas DataFrame to as `csv` to a directory I created in Databricks workspace.

pandas version `1.4.2`

```
import pandas as pd
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-1050805454984878>:2
      1 # Save CSV to Databricks filesystem
----> 2 df.to_csv(str(os.getcwd()) + "data.csv", index=False)

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:3551, in NDFrame.to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal, errors, storage_options)
   3540 df = self if isinstance(self, ABCDataFrame) else self.to_frame()
   3542 formatter = DataFrameFormatter(
   3543     frame=df,
   3544     header=header,
   (...)
   3548     decimal=decimal,
   3549 )
-> 3551 return DataFrameRenderer(formatter).to_csv(
   3552     path_or_buf,
   3553     line_terminator=line_terminator,
   3554     sep=sep,
   3555     encoding=encoding,
   3556     errors=errors,
   3557     compression=compression,
   3558     quoting=quoting,
   3559     columns=columns,
   3560     index_label=index_label,
   3561     mode=mode,
   3562     chunksize=chunksize,
   3563     quotechar=quotechar,
   3564     date_format=date_format,
   3565     doublequote=doublequote,
   3566     escapechar=escapechar,
   3567     storage_options=storage_options,
   3568 )

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py:1180, in DataFrameRenderer.to_csv(self, path_or_buf, encoding, sep, columns, index_label, mode, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, errors, storage_options)
   1159     created_buffer = False
   1161 csv_formatter = CSVFormatter(
   1162     path_or_buf=path_or_buf,
   1163     line_terminator=line_terminator,
   (...)
   1178     formatter=self.fmt,
   1179 )
-> 1180 csv_formatter.save()
   1182 if created_buffer:
   1183     assert isinstance(path_or_buf, StringIO)

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py:261, in CSVFormatter.save(self)
    241 with get_handle(
    242     self.filepath_or_buffer,
    243     self.mode,
   (...)
    249 
    250     # Note: self.encoding is irrelevant here
    251     self.writer = csvlib.writer(
    252         handles.handle,
    253         lineterminator=self.line_terminator,
   (...)
    258         quotechar=self.quotechar,
    259     )
--> 261     self._save()

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py:266, in CSVFormatter._save(self)
    264 if self._need_to_save_header:
    265     self._save_header()
--> 266 self._save_body()

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py:304, in CSVFormatter._save_body(self)
    302 if start_i >= end_i:
    303     break
--> 304 self._save_chunk(start_i, end_i)

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py:315, in CSVFormatter._save_chunk(self, start_i, end_i)
    312 data = [res.iget_values(i) for i in range(len(res.items))]
    314 ix = self.data_index[slicer]._format_native_types(**self._number_format)
--> 315 libwriters.write_csv_rows(
    316     data,
    317     ix,
    318     self.nlevels,
    319     self.cols,
    320     self.writer,
    321 )

File /databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/writers.pyx:72, in pandas._libs.writers.write_csv_rows()

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I was hoping to save it as a `csv` or `.pickle` file. I have also tried to specify the full absolute path of the directory.

Comment: `df.to_csv(str(os.getcwd()) + "data.csv", index=False)` I believe you need a slash in between those two things.  Try `+ "/data.csv"`

Comment: @JohnGordon I tried `df.to_csv(str(os.getcwd()) + "/data.csv", index=False)`, still getting the same error.

Comment: Hmm.  Can you try `print(str(os.getcwd()) + "/data.csv")` to see what it is using as the full filename?

Comment: @JohnGordon it looks ok: `/Workspace/Users/user-name/dir-name/data.csv`. This is what i'd expect.

Comment: Strange.  Since the current directory is the default anyway, can you just use `"data.csv"` without `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: @JohnGordon It's very strange. I get the same error with `df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)`. I am not able to save on the file system and keep getting `OSError`

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser.  What happens if you try to just `open()` a plain file for writing?  i.e. `open("example.txt", "w")`

Comment: `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='example.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>`

Comment: Well, the open worked, so it's not a file/directory problem.  I have no idea what the issue is.